# How to make a command to automate the processing of a list of commands

Tags: macros

The following works, and does what I want, except it would be better automated, because I want to do it many times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item   

\FPrandom{\rndA}
\FPrandom{\rndB}
\FPrandom{\rndC}
\FPeval{\uu}{trunc(11*\rndA, 0)}
\FPeval{\vv}{trunc(- 30 - 61*\rndB, 0)}
\FPeval{\ww}{trunc(101*\rndC + 100, 0)}

Some text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\global\edef\uu{\uu}
\global\edef\vv{\vv}
\global\edef\ww{\ww}

\end{enumerate}

More text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\end{document}
```

All my many attempts to automate have failed.  Here is the format of what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\MakeGlobDefs}[1]{
  This is the function input "unexpanded": \unexpanded{#1} % 
  % Loop over items in list #1 (possibly just one)
    \global\edef<command name>{<command value>}
  % end of loop
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item   

\FPrandom{\rndA}
\FPrandom{\rndB}
\FPrandom{\rndC}
\FPeval{\uu}{trunc(11*\rndA, 0)}
\FPeval{\vv}{trunc(- 30 - 61*\rndB, 0)}
\FPeval{\ww}{trunc(101*\rndC + 100, 0)}

Some text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\def\Glist{\uu,\vv,\ww}
\MakeGlobDefs{\Glist}

\end{enumerate}

More text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\end{document}
```

It seems that when I try to use my list of commands (`\Glist`) inside the `\MakeGlobDefs` function, they are already fully expanded.  So I can't even get to playing with the loop.  I have messed around extensively with the various commands that are supposed to control expansion, to no avail.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](//tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Another tip: There is a shortcut in TeX for `\global\edef` which is `\xdef`.

Comment: @dexteritas Thanks, but I don't see any backticks - where should I look?  What would they do?

Comment: @cwhctza Backticks are used to mark inline code (LaTeX commands etc.) in the text. You can click on the "edited ... ago" link to see the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MakeGlobDefs}[1]{%
  This is the function input "unexpanded":
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}$\rightarrow$
  \texttt{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}% 
  % Loop over items in list #1 (possibly just one)
  \@for\cs:={#1}\do{%
    \expandafter\xdef\cs{\cs}%
  }%
  % end of loop
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item   

\FPrandom{\rndA}
\FPrandom{\rndB}
\FPrandom{\rndC}
\FPeval{\uu}{trunc(11*\rndA, 0)}
\FPeval{\vv}{trunc(- 30 - 61*\rndB, 0)}
\FPeval{\ww}{trunc(101*\rndC + 100, 0)}

Some text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\def\Glist{\uu,\vv,\ww}
\MakeGlobDefs{\Glist}

\end{enumerate}

More text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\end{document}
```

Without the `\Glist` you could use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MakeGlobDefs}[1]{%
  \@for\cs:={\unexpanded{#1}}\do{%
    \expandafter\xdef\cs{\cs}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item   

\FPrandom{\rndA}
\FPrandom{\rndB}
\FPrandom{\rndC}
\FPeval{\uu}{trunc(11*\rndA, 0)}
\FPeval{\vv}{trunc(- 30 - 61*\rndB, 0)}
\FPeval{\ww}{trunc(101*\rndC + 100, 0)}

Some text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\MakeGlobDefs{\uu,\vv,\ww}

\end{enumerate}

More text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg now done.

Comment: Many, many thanks for this.  Both your examples do what I want, and yes doing it without defining the list is slightly tidier, and what I'd done at first.  So if I've understood correctly "\detokenize" prevents expansion, and "\texttt" allows the backslash to print correctly.

Comment: In the loop of your first example, where is says "\expandafter\xdef\cs{\cs}", the first "\expandafter" makes the first "\cs" expand once to an explicit item in the list, while the second "\cs" is fully expanded.  Right?

Comment: However, where it says "\texttt{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}", the purpose must be to allow a single expansion, but I'm not entirely sure if I get it.  The second "\expandafter" puts a hold on "{" and expands "#1" once.  Is that "#1" -> "\Glist", or "\Glist" -> "\uu,\vv,\ww"?  Must be the latter.  And is the first "\expandafter" needed so that "\detokenize" does not act on the second "\expandafter"?

Comment: In the loop of your second example, where is says "\@for\cs:={\unexpanded{#1}}\do{", I get that you have to prevent the list represented by "#1" from being expanded, but why does it work here, whereas it did not work in my example?  Also, why is "\unexpanded" appropriate here rather than "\detokenize"?

Comment: If you've already spend enough time, I'll understand.

Anyway, I'll go and try this out in my actual big latex file.

Comment: @cwhctza Answers in order of your comments: 1. yes one could say so. 2. Yes. 3. Yes. 4. `\unexpanded` prevents expansion (once) while the tokens aren't touched, whereas `\detokenize` changes the letters of a macro name (which is one token) into single tokens (each letter is one), that completely blocks any expansion of the macro.

Comment: This (second) solution is working nicely in my big file.

Comment: By the way, when I implemented @Skillmon's solution it occurred to me to put the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` inside the `\MakeGlobDefs` command definition.  This created errors.  I'd be curious to know why.

Comment: @cwhctza because a change of category codes (which is what `\makeatletter` does) is only possible outside a paragraph, so your macro can't change them where you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a better way to get random integers and to be able to use them anywhere.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setrandominteger}{mO{0}m}
 {
  \int_const:cn { c_cwhctza_#1_int } { \fp_eval:n { randint(#2,#3) } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\userandominteger}{m}
 {
  \ensuremath{\int_use:c { c_cwhctza_#1_int }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item
\setrandominteger{uu}{10}
\setrandominteger{vv}[-90]{-30}
\setrandominteger{ww}[100]{200}
Some text involving \userandominteger{uu}, \userandominteger{vv} \& \userandominteger{ww}.
\end{enumerate}

More text involving \userandominteger{uu}, \userandominteger{vv} \& \userandominteger{ww}.

\end{document}
```

The `\setrandominteger{<label>}[<lower>]{<upper>}` macro defines a random integer in the range `<lower>`–`<upper>` (inclusive); if the optional argument is missing, it defaults to 0.

You can recover the value by `\userandominteger{<label>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setrandominteger}{mO{0}m}
 {
  \int_const:cn { c_cwhctza_#1_int } { \fp_eval:n { randint(#2,#3) } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\userandominteger}{m}
 {
  \ensuremath{\int_use:c { c_cwhctza_#1_int }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item
\setrandominteger{uu}{10}
\setrandominteger{vv}[-90]{-30}
\setrandominteger{ww}[100]{200}
Some text involving \userandominteger{uu}, \userandominteger{vv} \& \userandominteger{ww}.
\end{enumerate}

More text involving \userandominteger{uu}, \userandominteger{vv} \& \userandominteger{ww}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can extend to support many other operations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setrandominteger}{mO{0}m}
 {
  \int_const:cn { c_cwhctza_#1_int } { \fp_eval:n { randint(#2,#3) } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printrandominteger}{m}
 {
  \ensuremath{\int_use:c { c_cwhctza_#1_int }}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\userandominteger}{m}
 {
  \int_use:c { c_cwhctza_#1_int }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfpvar}{mm}
 {
  \fp_const:cn { c_cwhctza_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printfpvar}{m}
 {
  \ensuremath{\fp_use:c { c_cwhctza_#1_fp }}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { c_cwhctza_#1_fp }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item   
\setrandominteger{uu}{10}
\setrandominteger{vv}[-90]{-30}
\setrandominteger{ww}[100]{200}
\setfpvar{abc}{exp(rand()) + sqrt(\userandominteger{uu})}
Some text involving \printrandominteger{uu}, \printrandominteger{vv},
\printrandominteger{ww} and \printfpvar{abc}.
\end{enumerate}

More text involving \printrandominteger{uu}, \printrandominteger{vv},
\printrandominteger{ww} and \printfpvar{abc}.

We can also do $\fpeval{round(\usefpvar{abc}+\userandominteger{vv},2)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spending time on my problem.  My real file does much more complex calculations, of which random integers is just the beginning.

Comment: @cwhctza `expl3` can manage essentially everything `fp` does.

Comment: @cwhctza I added some examples.

Comment: My question was about automating the "globalisation" of multiple commands declared inside an enumerate.  I didn't have a problem with FP.  The fragility of user commands declared inside enumerate is generic.  If `expl3` can make its declared variables global as it goes along, e.g. with a single setting, then I might be interested.

Comment: @cwhctza As you can see, those variables *are* declared globally