# How to store multiple fragile definitions for re-importing later

Tags: macros, write-file

I'm posting this in case it's useful to anyone; it's not actually a question.

Commands defined inside environments like enumerate are automatically fragile, and are lost outside the environment.  This is frequently inconvenient.  However, one can make the definitions global.  In my earlier question [How to make a command to automate the processing of a list of commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410797/how-to-make-a-command-to-automate-the-processing-of-a-list-of-commandsref), that @Skillmon solved for me, I wanted to know how to automate the make-it-global process for a specified list of (already defined) command names.  It's trickier than you might think.

Although this is a neat solution, if you do a lot of this in a large document, you have to be sure all your global definitions have different names.

If however, when you later need your commands outside their defining environment, they are only needed in a localised part of your document, it may make more sense to store those definitions in a file, and re-import them when you need them.  That way, different definition sets don't have to be given mutually exclusive sets of names.  As before, automating this is tricky.  Here's an example that works.  It includes improvements due to comments by @Skillmon, @egreg and @David Carlisle below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter % These "\makeat"s must be outside the newcommand
\newwrite\defsout
\newcommand{\WriteDefsToFile}[2]{%
  \immediate\openout\defsout=#1_defs.tex
  \@for\cs:={\unexpanded{#2}}\do{%
    \immediate\write\defsout{%
      \def\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\cs}{\cs}%
    }%
  }%
  \immediate\write\defsout{\unexpanded{ }}%
  \immediate\closeout\defsout
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\RandSeed{\the\year}

Start an enumerate.

\begin{enumerate}

\item   

Define some commands related to what this item's about.
\FPeval{\RnSd}{clip(\RandSeed*9876)} % It's not important what coomands are being defined
\FPseed\RnSd
\FPrandom{\rndA}
\FPrandom{\rndB}
\FPrandom{\rndC}
\FPeval{\uu}{trunc(11*\rndA, 0)}
\FPeval{\vv}{trunc(- 30 - 61*\rndB, 0)}
\FPeval{\ww}{trunc(101*\rndC + 100, 0)}

Some of the text involves these commands: \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\WriteDefsToFile{UVW}{\uu,\vv,\ww}

\end{enumerate}

%%% Following would give and "Undefined control sequence" error
%More text involving \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\input{UVW_defs}

After the enumerate, there's more text involving these commands: \uu, \vv\ \& \ww.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd put `\newwrite` outside of the command.

Comment: @Skillmon.  Thanks.  But why?  Is it more robust, or more efficient, or just neater?

Comment: @cwhctza Try calling `\WriteDefsToFile` sixteen times. Since you're allocating a new output stream per call, you'll exhaust the supply. This is where using `\newwrite` outside the definition of `\WriteDefsToFile` is important.

Comment: This is a question and answers site. You *should* ask a question that can be answered (by yourself, for instance).

Comment: as well as the misplaced `\newwrite` you are missing `%` at the ends of lines so the command will insert spaces into the document at the point you do the write (which may or may not affect the typesetting depending where you do that)

Comment: @egreg.  Thanks, I understand - important correction.

Comment: @David Carlisle.  Thanks - useful comment.

Comment: Thanks @David Carlisle for amending the placement of line-end `%`s

Comment: Also, for random numbers the year is a poor seed, but this is not related to your automation attempt :)

Comment: @Skilmon.  Thanks, but if you want the numbers to change only once a year, then it's quite a good seed.  (As I see it, the point of MWEs is to focus on the question being asked, meaning other aspects are so reduced that the intent cannot be discerned.)